# Rate my build - 5e New to DND need advice

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, tactics

Point Spread:

Attribute /Ability Score/ Racial Bonus/ Total Score/ Ability Modifier/

Strength /8/ /0/ /8/ /-1/

Dexterity /15/ /2/ /17/ /+3/

Constitution /15/ /0/ /15/ /+2/

Intelligence /10/ /0/ /10/ /0/

Wisdom /14/ /0/ /14/ /+2/

Charisma /8/ /1/ /9/ /-1/

Mark of the Shadow Elf (Dex +2 Char +1)

Have access to misdirection/Utility spells and invisibility once a day plus 1d4 added to any stealth or performance roll

Will Attempt to be poison boy with Poison kit and make poisons to debuff enemies on hit (cause blindness or damage etc.)

Ranger 4 -Swarm Keeper

Starting with this mainly for for Stealth prof, Hunter's Mark, The Swarm Extra 1d6 Damage/Utility (Mage Hand), Archery Fighting style, Deft Explorer for doubling stealth prof on roll.

Fighter 12- Echo Knight

Getting staple Action Surge, Extra attack x2, Fighting style -Superior Technique of getting Sup Die for Precision attack

For the echo knight portion playstyle would be to stealth then attack from echo position and switch out short sword for Unleash Incarnation for another attack to proc hunters mark. Echo knight will also be there to OP attacks to proc hunters mark again.

Rogue 2-

Getting Expertise for Sleight of hand prof (would like to steal;) and Thieves tools. Getting Sneak attack, Cunning Action (to hide/disengage/dash bonus action)

Cleric 2- War Cleric

Extra spell slots, War Priest (another Extra attack or bonus action), Channel Divinity -Guided Strike, Divine Favor of extra damage as well.

Feats/ ASI- Going Sentinel (for the Echo knight) and Martial Adept (for 2 more Battle Master Maneuvers and 1 dice) Looking into more feats but 3 ASI sounds nice too Gunna max DEX and one more into Con for 16 fersure then I guess 2 into wisdom for another modifier?

Spell Slots

Ending up with 4 -1st Level Spell Slots and 3 second level

All Together Really just capitalizing on adding damage to bow hit and securing the hit with high DEX potentially +8 or +9 to attack roll, Guided strike and using Superiority die for Precision attack for more attack roll. (to start Procing the Damage and debuff with poison)

In Theory MAX Damage output Turn would be Longbow(1d8)+Swarm(1d6)+Hunters Mark(1d6)+Sneak attack(1d8) Also hopefully applying poison(debuff)+ Extra attack 1 bow(1d8)+ Hunters mark(1d6) + Extra attack 2 bow(1d8)+Hunters Mark(1d6)+ War Priest Bonus action to use bow again(1d8) +Hunters Mark(1d6)+Action Surge bow(1d8)+Hunters Mark(1d6)+Unleash Incarnation Short Sword(1d6)+Hunters Mark(1d6)

Leaving sword out for Echo to make OP attack when my turn is over

Still new tho am I understanding all this correctly? Hunter's mark is not once per turn and is on "weapon attack" so should this work?

Any Advice on how to optimize or add anything? or fix something?

Comment: We don’t really do “rate my build” sort of questions. If you have a specific question about how something works, it’s probably on topic, but as written this question is opinion based.

Comment: Hi, you might have better luck on a traditional forum (e.g. reddit.com/r/3d6)

Comment: I concur with Raj. Here is a curated list of RPG-related forums that we recommend: https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/41726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Poison

Poisons in 5e are simply bad. Majority of stuff is immune to poison, the damage is negligible and the poisons are poor use of action economy. Unless your DM is generous and gives you access to some powerful DMG only poisons, you're not getting much value out of poison.

#### Sentinel and Echo Knight interaction

Depending on how strict your DM is with rules, this might not work - you can only attack with the echo during **Attack action on your turn** or using its specific reaction. This means you cannot use an echo for War Priest's bonus action attack, nor for Sentinel's reaction attack.

#### Level progression

You didn't specify what sort of campaign you'll be playing, but it's very important to realise that most of campaign end at or around 12th level. Last few levels are gonna be finishing touches for your build, not something you should base it on.

If you're gonna start with ranger up to level 4, you're gonna get first Extra Attack at level 9 total. This means you've got levels 5-8 where a pure classed martial is attacking twice as much.

#### Suggestions

What I'd do with this build is first of all, drop the War Cleric. Playing such high levels is unlikely, and even if you do, it's not worth sacrifing stuff earlier on to fit this into the build.

With that out of the way, I'd focus on one of two classes - either Ranger or Fighter and bring it up to level 5 initially for that extra attack.

If you want to stick to the general core of your build, that'd be Fighter 5, grabbing Echo Knight and ASI (imho, +1 Dex +1 Con would be best). Then you can branch out to Ranger 3 and Rogue 3 for the additional stuff you mentioned. Some rogue subclasses offer really cool stuff so it's worth checking them out. Just don't fall into Assassin's trap. If none fits you you can drop back to Rogue 2.

With this core you are at level 10-11 and can do most of the cool stuff you wanted and should be able to figure out how to progress from there on your own based on your campaign. Maxing out one of the classes would probably work best.